Create a category column or a table for each category?
Which is better?
Table: Words
Columns: ID, Word, ParentWordID, CatID

Table: Categories
Columns: CatID, Category

Or:
Table: Words
Columns: ID, Word

Table: Categories
Columns: CatID, Categories

Table: Cat1
Columns: WordID
...
Table: CatN
Columns: WordID

One possible advantage for the 2nd option is that not all Words need to have a category. But the same could be said for ParentWordID, which is empty most of the time. Maybe that too could be replaced with a Parents table and a table for each parent?

Option is also good.What is the diffrence between option 1 and junction table ?Option is little denormalise

Neither. Use a junction table to model a many-to-many relationship.
